# AdonisJS 5 - preload model even if foreign key is null

Tags: javascript, adonis.js, lucid

I want to preload a model even if it have a null foreign key.
I'll use the models from Adonis docs page to ilustrate: User and Profile.

```
const user = await User.query().preload("profile")
```

Simple as that!

But in my case, **if a user have the key profile_id as null, it throws an exception**, what means it only preload existing relationships (fair enough).

To make clear, I not want to preload just users with existing foreign keys, I need **both** existing user related models **and** users with no models to preload.

I have read and tested the examples from [docs](https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/model-relations/introduction#preloading-relationship) page, but it haven't enough explanation about this case (or I just didn't found it).

Any hints will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me first answer your question, **YES**, you can preload **Fk** which are **NULL**.

PS - you have not given any details apart from the query, so i am going to make some assumptions.

Explanation-

1. First you have to define relationship before using preload
2. Relationsgip should be defined in the table which contains **FK**, in our case, its **User** table.
   e.g

```
//User.ts or User.js
import Profile from '/path/to/profile';

...
  @column()
  public profileId: number;

  @belongsTo(() => Profile)
  public profile: BelongsTo<typeof Profile>;
...
```

As you can see, i have created a relationship in user table.
i.e

```
  @belongsTo(() => Profile)
  public profile: BelongsTo<typeof Profile>;
```

Once this is done, you can query user and preload profile.

```
const user = await User.query().preload("profile")
```

Now, if the user has profile, then it will be preloaded (join), and output will be something like this

```
User {
 id: <random-number>,
 profileId: <random-number>,
 profile: {
  ...
 },
 ...
}
```

in case, profileId is null, then output will be something like this

```
User {
 id: <random-number>,
 profileId: null,
 ...
}
```

ps - `user` variable is an array of User instance and i have given example of just 1 User instance.

I hope this explanation has helped you.